# Lookup against MYSQL TEXT type column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My table/model has `TEXT` type column, and when filtering for the records on the model itself, the AR `where` produces the correct SQL and returns correct results, here is what I mean :

```
MyNamespace::MyValue.where(value: 'Good Quality')
```

Produces this SQL :

```
SELECT `my_namespace_my_values`.* 
FROM `my_namespace_my_values` 
WHERE `my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = '\\\"Good Quality\\\"'
```

Take another example where I m joining `MyNamespace::MyValue` and filtering on the same `value` column but from the other model (has relation on the model to `my_values`). See this (**query #2**) :

```
OtherModel.joins(:my_values).where(my_values: { value: 'Good Quality' })
```

This does not produce correct query, this filters on the `value` column as if it was a String column and not Text, therefore producing incorrect results like so (only pasting relevant where) :

```
WHERE my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = 'Good Quality'
```

Now I can get past this by doing LIKE inside my AR `where`, which will produce the correct result but slightly different query. This is what I mean :

```
OtherModel.joins(:my_values).where('my_values.value LIKE ?, '%Good Quality%')
```

Finally arriving to my questions. **What is this and how it's being generated for where on the model (for text column type)?**

```
WHERE `my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = '\\\"Good Quality\\\"'
```

Maybe most important question **what is the difference in terms of performance using** :

```
WHERE `my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = '\\\"Good Quality\\\"'
```

and this :

```
(my_namespace_my_values.value LIKE '%Good Quality%')
```

and more importantly **how do I get my query with joins (query #2) produce where like this** :

```
WHERE `my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = '\\\"Good Quality\\\"'
```

Comment: What Rails plugin are you using?

Comment: @RickJames No plugin

Comment: Then what is generating all the backslashes and the quotes?

Comment: What version of rails and mysql are you using?

Comment: Active record I guess @RickJames , rails 4.2.10 and here is info about mysql `"innodb_version", "5.6.27"], ["protocol_version", "10"], ["slave_type_conversions", ""], ["version", "5.6.27-log"], ["version_comment", "MySQL Community Server (GPL)"], ["version_compile_machine", "x86_64"], ["version_compile_os", "Linux"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Partial answer -- approaching from the MySQL side.)

**What will/won't match**

Case 1:  (I don't know where the extra backslashes and quotes come from.)

```
WHERE `my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = '\\\"Good Quality\\\"'

\"Good Quality\"               -- matches
Good Quality                   -- does not match
The product has Good Quality.  -- does not match
```

Case 2:  (Find `Good Quality` anywhere in `value`.)

```
WHERE my_namespace_my_values.value LIKE '%Good Quality%'

\"Good Quality\"               -- matches
Good Quality                   -- matches
The product has Good Quality.  -- matches
```

Case 3:

```
WHERE `my_namespace_my_values`.`value` = 'Good Quality'

\"Good Quality\"               -- does not match
Good Quality                   -- matches
The product has Good Quality.  -- does not match
```

**Performance:**

- If `value` is declared `TEXT`, all cases are slow.
- If `value` is not indexed, all are slow.
- If `value` is `VARCHAR(255)` (or smaller) *and* indexed, Cases 1 and 3 are faster.  It can quickly find the one row, versus checking all rows.

Phrased differently:

- `LIKE` with a *leading* wildcard (`%`) is slow.
- Indexing the column is important for performance, but `TEXT` cannot be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

The '=' op is looking for an exact match while the LIKE op is working more like pattern matching with '%' being similar like '*' in regular expressions.

So if you have entries with

1. Good Quality
2. More Good Quality

only LIKE will get both results.

Regarding the escape string I am not sure where this is generated, but looks like some standardized escaping to get this valid for SQL.

Answer (score 2):

> What is this and how it's being generated for where on the model (for
>   text column type)?

Thats generated behind Active Records (Arel) lexical engine.
See  my answer below on your second question as to why.

> What is the difference in terms of performance using...

The "=" matches by whole string/chunk comparison
While LIKE matches by character(s) ( by character(s)).

In my projects i got tables with millions of rows, from my experience its really faster to the use that comparator "=" or regexp than using a LIKE in a query.

> How do I get my query with joins (query #2) produce where like this...

Can you try this,

```
OtherModel.joins(:my_values).where(OtherModel[:value].eq('\\\"Good Quality\\\"'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be helpful.

> to search for \n, specify it as \n. To search for \, specify it as
>   \\ this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser
>   and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash
>   to be matched against.

[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

LIKE and = are different operators.

= is a comparison operator that operates on numbers and strings. When comparing strings, the comparison operator compares whole strings.

LIKE is a string operator that compares character by character.

```
mysql> SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+-----------------------------------------+
| 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       0 |
+-----------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+--------------------------------------+
| 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
```